# Using buttons on number input will not update the first input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So I'm trying to make the first input = the same as the second input on change, the arrows accomplish this, but the buttons which also change the second input doesn't pass on the value to the first input

working jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ryoLvedx/1/

```js
function passonvalue(value) {
    return (value);
} 

$('[name="quantity2"]').on('change', function() {
    value = $(this).val();
    $('[name="quantity"]').val(passonvalue(value));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="QuantitySelector__CurrentQuantity" pattern="[0-9]*" name="quantity" value="1">

<input type="button" class="QuantitySelector__Button Link Link--secondary second-quantity" value="-" onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepDown()" />
<input class="quantity" min="10" step="10" name="quantity2" value="10" type="number" />
<input type="button" class="QuantitySelector__Button Link Link--secondary second-quantity" value="+" onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepUp()" class="plus"/>
```

Comment: i think you have to trigger the change event, when the button is pressed.

Comment: @MirkoBrunner derp, thank you i was so focused on others, didnt see i needed to put the click event on the buttons rather than a click/change on the value of the number input

Comment: Either trigger the `change`-event manually, or use a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). You can configure the `MutationObserver` to only listen for attribute-changes.